# Change color of selected tab in shinydashboard tabBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way to change the color that indicates the active tab of a shinydashboard tabBox? I have changed the "skin" of the dashboard to "red". While this affects the highlighted active tab of the sidebar, it does not seem to have an effect regarding the selected tab in a tabBox.

I have only found solutions for changing the acutal background color of a selected tab (e.g., [Shinydashboard - Change background based on selected tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358329/shinydashboard-change-background-based-on-selected-tab)), however, I could not find anything regarding the little line on top of a selected tab in a tabBox. In my examples, the selected tabs (Tab1, Tab3, Tab1) should have a red indicator instead of the blue one the have now.

```r
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box

    body <- dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            tabBox(
                title = "First tabBox",
                # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
                id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
                tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
                tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
            ),
            tabBox(
                side = "right", height = "250px",
                selected = "Tab3",
                tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1"),
                tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
                tabPanel("Tab3", "Note that when side=right, the tab order is reversed.")
            )
        ),
        fluidRow(
            tabBox(
                # Title can include an icon
                title = tagList(shiny::icon("gear"), "tabBox status"),
                tabPanel("Tab1",
                         "Currently selected tab from first box:",
                         verbatimTextOutput("tabset1Selected")
                ),
                tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
            )
        )
    )

    shinyApp(
        ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), skin = "red", dashboardSidebar(), body),
        server = function(input, output) {
            # The currently selected tab from the first box
            output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
                input$tabset1
            })
        }
    )
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7512
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ----------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  German_Germany.1252         
#>  ctype    German_Germany.1252         
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2019-10-18                  
#> 
#> - Packages --------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package        * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat       0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  backports        1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  callr            3.3.2   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  cli              1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  crayon           1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.4.2)
#>  curl             4.1     2019-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  desc             1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  devtools         2.2.1   2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  digest           0.6.21  2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  ellipsis         0.3.0   2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  evaluate         0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  fs               1.3.1   2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  glue             1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  highr            0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  htmltools        0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  httpuv           1.5.2   2019-09-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  httr             1.4.1   2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  jsonlite         1.6     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  knitr            1.25    2019-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  later            0.8.0   2019-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  magrittr         1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.4.1)
#>  memoise          1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.4.1)
#>  mime             0.7     2019-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pkgbuild         1.0.5   2019-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pkgload          1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  prettyunits      1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  processx         3.4.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  promises         1.0.1   2018-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  ps               1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  R6               2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  Rcpp             1.0.2   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  remotes          2.1.0   2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  rlang            0.4.0   2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  rmarkdown        1.15    2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  rprojroot        1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  sessioninfo      1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  shiny          * 1.3.2   2019-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  shinydashboard * 0.7.1   2018-10-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  stringi          1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  stringr          1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  testthat         2.2.1   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  usethis          1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  webshot          0.5.1   2018-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  withr            2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  xfun             0.9     2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  xml2             1.2.2   2019-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  xtable           1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  yaml             2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#> 
#> [1] E:/R_LIBS_USER
#> [2] E:/R-3.6.1/library
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply custom `css` this. The red color used in `skin = "red"` is `#d73925`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- '.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active {
    border-top-color: #d73925;
}"'

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(js),
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    ),
    tabBox(
      side = "right", height = "250px",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab3", "Note that when side=right, the tab order is reversed.")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      # Title can include an icon
      title = tagList(shiny::icon("gear"), "tabBox status"),
      tabPanel("Tab1",
               "Currently selected tab from first box:",
               verbatimTextOutput("tabset1Selected")
      ),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), skin = "red", dashboardSidebar(), body),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      input$tabset1
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use the tag$style(js) locally to affect only the tabBox of one module?

Comment: u need to know the id of the nav-bar, so right-click and see in inspect element

Comment: I found a part where states class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabsetid="3184" . Where can I provide given id to the css code?

Comment: You may need to write some js to keep track of those ids as those are dynamically created by shiny internals